# How to install Sxslt package on Windows? R

Tags: xml, windows, r, xslt, installation

In relation to this question, I need to install **Sxslt package** in R on a windows platform. I used RStudio to compile the package from the source, but it encountered an error. It returned a message about defining **LIB_XSLT**. Please see the log below:

```
> install.packages("Sxslt", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")
Installing package(s) into ‘local/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'www.omegahat.org/R/src/contrib/Sxslt_0.91-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 112790 bytes (110 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 110 Kb

* installing *source* package 'Sxslt' ...
Please define LIB_XSLT
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'Sxslt'
* removing 'local/R/win-library/2.15/Sxslt'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'local/bin/i386/R CMD INSTALL -l "local/R/win-library/2.15" local/downloaded_packages/Sxslt_0.91-1.tar.gz' 
had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Sxslt’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘local\downloaded_packages’
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Sxslt` package which were provided by [Omega Project](http://www.omegahat.net/) is outdated now. It is better to use `xslt` package available at CRAN.

```
install.packages("xslt")
```