# Python/R: generate dataframe from XML when not all nodes contain all variables?

Tags: python, r, xml, pandas, xml2

Consider the following `XML` example

```
library(xml2)

myxml <- read_xml('
<data>
  <obs ID="a">
  <name> John </name>
  <hobby> tennis </hobby>
  <hobby> golf </hobby>
  <skill> python  </skill>
  </obs>
  <obs ID="b">
  <name> Robert </name>
  <skill> R </skill>
  </obs>
  </data>
')
```

Here I would like to get an (R or Pandas) dataframe from this XML that contains the columns `name` and `hobby`.

However, as you see, there is an alignment problem because `hobby` is missing in the second node and John has two hobbies.

in R, I know how to extract specific values one at a time, for instance using `xml2` as follows:

```
myxml%>% 
  xml_find_all("//name") %>% 
  xml_text()

myxml%>% 
  xml_find_all("//hobby") %>% 
  xml_text()
```

but how can I align this data correctly in a dataframe? That is, how can I obtain a dataframe as follows (note how I join with a `|` the two hobbies of John):

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    name           hobby            skill
   <chr>           <chr>            <chr>
1   John          tennis|golf       python
2 Robert            <NA>            R
```

In R, I would prefer a solution using `xml2` and `dplyr`. In Python, I want to end-up with a Pandas dataframe. Also, in my xml there are many more variables I want to parse. I would like a solution that has allows the user to parse additional variables without messing too much with the code.

Thanks!

EDIT: thanks to everyone for these great solutions. All of them were really nice, with plenty of details and it was hard to pick up the best one. Thanks again!

Comment: Thx. Mabye sth in the veins of `myxml %>% xml_find_all("/data/obs") %>% map(function(x) sapply(c("name","hobby"), function(y) xml_text(xml_find_first(x,y)))) %>% do.call(rbind, .)`?

Comment: maybe can you put this as a solution and explain what you are doing with the `sapply`? thanks again~

Comment: yw. I will add is as an answer if no better options pops up. Somehow it feels like it's a solution, but not really a good one. Let's wait...

Comment: I edited the question to be more broad. A solution in Python is also good

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446888/r-convert-xml-data-to-data-frame) is an imho interesting post, which has got an R and a Python solution. (E.g. I wonder if this all can be mimicked using the `reticulate` package & RStudio. hmm)

Comment: thx but not sure this solution works when there are missing nodes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`pandas`**

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml_txt = """<data>
  <obs ID="a">
  <name> John </name>
  <hobby> tennis </hobby>
  <hobby> golf </hobby>
  <skill> python  </skill>
  </obs>
  <obs ID="b">
  <name> Robert </name>
  <skill> R </skill>
  </obs>
  </data>"""

etree = ET.fromstring(xml_txt)

def obs2series(o):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    [d[c.tag].append(c.text.strip()) for c in o.getchildren()];
    return pd.Series(d).str.join('|')

pd.DataFrame([obs2series(o) for o in etree.findall('obs')])

         hobby    name   skill
0  tennis|golf    John  python
1          NaN  Robert       R
```

---

**How It Works**

- build an element tree from the string.  Otherwise do something like `et = ET.parse('my_data.xml')`
- `etree.findall('obs')` returns a list of elements within the `xml` structure that are `'obs'` tags
- I pass each of these to a `pd.Series` constructor `obs2series`
- Within `obs2series` I loop through all child nodes in one `'obs'` element.
- `defaultdict` defaults to a `list` meaning I can append to a value even if the key hasn't been seen before.
- I end up with a dictionary of lists.  I pass this to `pd.Series` to get a series of lists.
- Using `pd.Series.str.join('|')` I convert this to a series of strings as I wanted.
- My list comprehension in the beginning that looped over observations is now a list of series and ready to passed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

Comment: thanks man! nice one. do you mind explaining a bit what you are doing in the function? I am not super familiar with `xml.etree`

Comment: @Noobie hopefully that helps

Comment: thanks do you think this is robust to many duplicates or missing nodes? is the performance good?

Comment: @Noobie it's robust for many duplicates as the lists just get longer and the join just joins them.  I have to loop over all child nodes in each observation.  I've wrapped both in comprehensions.  Performance should be decent, no money back guarantees or anything.  BTW, I've updated the function.

Answer (score 4):

A general R solution that does not require to hardcode the variables.
Using `xml2` and tidyverse's `purrr`:

```r
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

myxml %>% 
  xml_find_all('obs') %>%      
  # Enter each obs and return a df
  map_df(~{

    # Scan names
    node_names <- .x %>% 
      xml_children() %>% 
      xml_name() %>%
      unique()        

    # Remember ob
    ob <- .x

    # Enter each node
    map(node_names, ~{

      # Find similar nodes
      node <- xml_find_all(ob, .x) %>%
        xml_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
        paste0(collapse = '|') %>% 
        'names<-'(.x)
        # ^ we need to name the element to 
        #   overwrite it with its 'sibilings'

    }) %>% 
      # Return an 'ob' vector
      flatten()        
  })

#> # A tibble: 2 Ã— 3
#>     name       hobby  skill
#>    <chr>       <chr>  <chr>
#> 1   John tennis|golf python
#> 2 Robert        <NA>      R
```

#### What it does:

1. It 'enters' each `obs`, find and store the node names in that obs.
2. For each node find all the similar node in the `obs`, collapse them and store in a list.
3. Flattens the list, overwriting elements with the same name.
4. `rbind` (implicit in `map_df()`) each 'flatted' list into the resulting `data.frame`.

#### Data:

```r
myxml <- read_xml('
                  <data>
                  <obs ID="a">
                  <name> John </name>
                  <hobby> tennis </hobby>
                  <hobby> golf </hobby>
                  <skill> python  </skill>
                  </obs>
                  <obs ID="b">
                  <name> Robert </name>
                  <skill> R </skill>
                  </obs>
                  </data>
                  ')
```

Comment: hi ! thanks for the answer. Why do you think it will not perform well with multiple duplicates? it is indeed the case in my data....

Comment: I guess it's more an inefficiency then a poor performance issue. For each node, (eg `hobby`), it will find all its similar nodes, (`xml_find_all('hobby')`). And then only keep the last anyway.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, a simple `unique()` on the `node_names` would remove the issue.. silly me..

Comment: hi ! just a few remarks. I dont understand the syntax for `node_names <- .x` (why is there a dot?) and  ( `'names<-'(.x)` what does that mean? )

Comment: also, why the tilda in `map(node_names, ~{`. man, your code is too refined for a noobie like me :D

Comment: summoning @ggamba

Comment: in a `purrr::map*` function and many others in same package, `~` is a shortcut for `function(x)` and in the expression following it,  `.` or `.x` represents the `x` argument. `purrr` provides great alternatives to `*apply`, `map`, `reduce` and other functional programming base R functions. You can read [more about purrr here](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: @GGamba Thanks, it helped me a lot!. I don't understand the 'names<-' (.x) though, and why it have to be flattened at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In R, I'd probably use

```
library(XML)
lst <- xmlToList(xmlParse(myxml)[['/data']])
(df <- data.frame(t(sapply(lst, function(x) {
  c(x['name'], hobby=paste0(x[which(names(x)=='hobby')], collapse="|"))
}))) )
#       name           hobby
# 1    John   tennis | golf 
# 2  Robert
```

and maybe do some polishing using `df[df==""] <- NA` and `trimws()` to remove whitespaces.

---

Or:

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
`%|||%` <- function (x, y) if (length(x)==0) y else x 
(df <- data_frame(
  names = myxml %>% 
    xml_find_all("/data/obs/name") %>% 
    xml_text(trim=TRUE), 
  hobbies = myxml %>% 
    xml_find_all("/data/obs") %>% 
    lapply(function(x) xml_text(xml_find_all(x, "hobby"), T) %|||% NA_character_)
))
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#    names   hobbies
#    <chr>    <list>
# 1   John <chr [2]>
# 2 Robert <chr [1]>
```

Comment: thanks! can you just please explain a bit what you are doing with the `sapply` stuff?

Comment: I mean, can you just decompose a bit what you are doing here? `(df <- data.frame(t(sapply(lst, function(x) {
  c(x['name'], hobby=paste0(x[which(names(x)=='hobby')], collapse="|"))`? thanks!

Comment: @Noobie `sapply` loops through the list and grabs the values named _name_ and named _hobby_. I used `which` because there can be multiple hobbies. Each iteration returns a vector of names and pipe-seperated hobbies.

Comment: @Noobie However, if your xml is very big, using a list is probably not the best way. Maybe something like `\`%|||%\` <- function (x, y) { if (length(x)==0) y else x }; data_frame(names = myxml %>% xml_find_all("/data/obs/name") %>% xml_text(trim=TRUE), hobbies = myxml %>% xml_find_all("/data/obs") %>% lapply(function(x) xml_text(xml_find_all(x, "hobby"), T) %|||% NA_character_))` to get back to xml2 and dplyr? I'd rather store the hobbies in a list rather then pipe seperated...

Comment: thanks! do you mind adding this solution to your previous solution? it is hard to read right now. btw what the hell is ``%|||%` <-` ? :D never seen that in my noob R life!

Comment: @Noobie You are right, just did so; I stole that one shamelessly from `purrr::\`%||%\`` (<- works for NULL values, but I needed one for 0-lengths). But I guess it's more of less a show-off. ;-)

Comment: the `xml2` solution is very elegant, but the dataframe now contains a list of characters? how can you get exactly the output desired? thanks!

Comment: invoking @lukeA

Comment: @Noobie: I deleted previous comment, I dunno how I came up with it. Just do `df$hobbies <- sapply(df$hobbies,paste,collapse=",")`.

Answer (score 1):

### XML

Create a function that can handle missing or multiple nodes, and then apply that to the `obs` nodes.   I added the id column so you can see how to use `xmlGetAttr` too (use `"."` for the obs node and the leading `"."` on other nodes so its relative to that current node in the set).

```
xpath2 <-function(x, ...){
    y <- xpathSApply(x, ...)
    ifelse(length(y) == 0, NA,  paste(trimws(y), collapse=", "))
}  
obs <- getNodeSet(doc, "//obs")   
data.frame( id = sapply(obs, xpath2, ".", xmlGetAttr, "ID"),
          name = sapply(obs, xpath2, ".//name", xmlValue),
       hobbies = sapply(obs, xpath2, ".//hobby", xmlValue),
         skill = sapply(obs, xpath2, ".//skill", xmlValue))

  id   name      hobbies  skill
1  a   John tennis, golf python
2  b Robert         <NA>      R
```

### xml2

I don't use `xml2` very often, but maybe get the `obs` nodes and then apply `xml_find_all` if there are duplicate tags instead of using `xml_find_first`.

```
obs <-  xml_find_all(myxml, "//obs")  
lapply(obs, xml_find_all, ".//hobby")

data_frame(
     name = xml_find_first(obs, ".//name") %>% xml_text(trim=TRUE),
  hobbies = sapply(obs, function(x)  paste(xml_text( xml_find_all(x, ".//hobby"), trim=TRUE), collapse=", " ) ),
    skill = xml_find_first(obs, ".//skill") %>% xml_text(trim=TRUE)
)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
    name      hobbies  skill
   <chr>        <chr>  <chr>
1   John tennis, golf python
2 Robert                   R
```

I tested both methods using the `medline17n0853.xml` file at the [NCBI ftp](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/baseline). This is a 280 MB file with 30,000 PubmedArticle nodes, and the XML package took 102 seconds to parse pubmed ids, journals and combine multiple publication types.   The xml2 code ran for 30 minutes and then I killed it, so that may not be the best solution.

Comment: thanks Chris, this is great. However, I was asking for a `xml2` solution because it appears to be more robust to memory leaks and my XML is very large. Can you adapt your code using this similar package?

Comment: You may be trying to avoid a problem that doesn't exist, except maybe 
for people who use Windows and loop through XML files to create new xml docs for each node?

Comment: well I use windows :D

Comment: thanks. I am trying to understand why your xml2 solution is not efficient.

Comment: so do you know why yoyr solution in xm2 fails?