# Trying to convert XML into a dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I am downloading the zip files from the location
http://nemweb.com.au/Data_Archive/Wholesale_Electricity/NEMDE/2019/NEMDE_2019_03/NEMDE_Market_Data/NEMDE_Files/NemPriceSetter_20190301_xml.zip

The zip file has multiple xml files inside which iam trying to read but based on the style of the XML file I cannot parse it properly and cannot convert that into a data frame

I have tried to download the zip file into a temporary directory and then tried parsing one file at a time

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

tf <- tempfile(tmpdir = tdir <- tempdir())
download.file("http://nemweb.com.au/Data_Archive/Wholesale_Electricity/NEMDE/2019/NEMDE_2019_03/NEMDE_Market_Data/NEMDE_Files/NemPriceSetter_20190301_xml.zip", tf)
xml_files <- unzip(tf, exdir = tdir)

library(XML)

doc<-xmlParse(xml_files[1])
a<-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//SolutionAnalysis/PriceSetting"))

unlink(tdir, T, T)
```

This is how the XML file looks 
[image]

and I am trying to put the information in a specific column using a data frame

Comment: I reckon found the answer to that by using

Comment: df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(tagsXML, path='//PriceSetting'))

Comment: If you found the answer please post it as an answer. You can answer your own questions.

Comment: Check this link. This might be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446888/r-convert-xml-data-to-data-frame]