# Converting a xml page to a data frame

Tags: r, xml, parsing

I am trying to use the R package, in order to get into a dataframe the values of the 'nonDerivativeTable' node of the following US government table, reporting insider trading data.

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274494/000112760222021374/form4.xml

I have tried both the XML and the XML2 packages and followed the example given here: [R: convert XML data to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446888/r-convert-xml-data-to-data-frame)

But I had no luck, probably because the two xml pages are very different,

I would really appreciate any help more specifically to my example.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this URL:

1. It **does not accept requests from R directly**. We have to simulate that we use a browser to access it. We can do this by using the right request headers:

```r
library(xml2)
library(httr2)
resp <- request("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274494/000112760222021374/form4.xml") |> 
  req_headers(
    "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" = "1",
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept" = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0",
    "Connection" = "keep-alive"
  ) |> 
  req_perform() |> 
  resp_body_xml()
```

Now we have received an xml object. We can convert this into a list:

```
resp_l <- resp |> 
  as_list() |> 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

2. The **data in the xml is not rectangular**. If it was, we could simply convert this to a data.frame but some entries are longer than others. Some are nested etc. The only thing we can do is look through the object (e.g., with `´View(resp_l)`) and look for the information you want. Then you can piece together a data.frame:

```
data.frame(
  issuerName = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.issuer"]][["issuerName"]][[1]],
  rptOwnerStreet1 = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.reportingOwner"]][["reportingOwnerAddress"]][["rptOwnerStreet1"]][[1]],
  rptOwnerStreet2 = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.reportingOwner"]][["reportingOwnerAddress"]][["rptOwnerStreet2"]][[1]],
  rptOwnerCity = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.reportingOwner"]][["reportingOwnerAddress"]][["rptOwnerCity"]][[1]],
  rptOwnerState = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.reportingOwner"]][["reportingOwnerAddress"]][["rptOwnerState"]][[1]],
  rptOwnerZipCode = resp_l[["ownershipDocument.reportingOwner"]][["reportingOwnerAddress"]][["rptOwnerZipCode"]][[1]]
)
#>          issuerName       rptOwnerStreet1                       rptOwnerStreet2
#> 1 FIRST SOLAR, INC. C/O FIRST SOLAR, INC. 350 WEST WASHINGTON STREET, SUITE 600
#>   rptOwnerCity rptOwnerState rptOwnerZipCode
#> 1        TEMPE            AZ      85281-1244
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried to paste the code in the first box and I get the following error message:

Comment: Error: unexpected '>' in "resp <- request("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1274494/000112760222021374/form4.xml") |>"

Comment: Do you maybe have an old version of R? The `|>` pipe was only introduced in R 4.1. You can use `%>%` instead (from `magrittr`).

Comment: Ah... you are right: I was stuck with version 3.6.3! However, the %>% does the trick.

Comment: Just one thing: when I type: 'resp_l$ownershipDocument.nonDerivativeTable$nonDerivativeTransaction$transactionAmounts', it shows only the first transaction, whereas there are 4 of them in the form. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: That's annoying. They all have the same name. You have to resort to using indices (`resp_l[["ownershipDocument.nonDerivativeTable"]][[2]][["transactionAmounts"]]`) or loop over them: `lapply(resp_l[["ownershipDocument.nonDerivativeTable"]], function(x) x[["transactionAmounts"]])`

Comment: `xml2` also has some great tools built in like `xml_find_all`, but that's beyond the scope of the question. You would need to be more specific in what you want.

Comment: Terrific job! Appreciated.